# Run as TestNG not appearing in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng

I am trying to setup TestNG and run a sample test using TestNG.
I have installed the TestNG plugin in Eclipse but when I try to run the test as TestNG, the option is not showing in 'Run As', it only shows Run As JUnit. 
Can anyone tell the reason why it is not appearing? or am I missing something?

I tried uninstalling TestNG and re-installing it again, but no go..

One more thing, am I not allowed to use JUnit and TestNG at the same time?
My eclipse has got just the JUnit in Window -> Preferences -> Java -> JUnit but I can't see TestNG, why is this?

Please advise.

Thanks.

Comment: If TestNG is not displayed in "running configuration" nor "preferences" and you don't have the view "TestNG", then the plugin is probably incorrectly installed. Check under `Help > About > Installation Details > Plug-ins` and see if listed

Comment: The file that you are trying to run: what are the imports?

Comment: I have imported the following:
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

Comment: @flafoux, I have checked Plug-ins tab as you suggested, couldn't find testng plugin in there. 
Steps I followed to install testng in Eclipse (Luna)
1. Clicked on Help on tool bar.
2. Clicked on Install New Software.
3. Entered http://beust.com/eclipse in work with and gone through the installation procedure. 

Please suggest if am doing anything wrong.

Comment: check your `workspace/.metadata/.log` for potential errors

Comment: Saw the log file as advised.. saw below lines of error message:
!ENTRY org.testng.eclipse 4 0 2015-07-01 16:44:42.486
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.testng.eclipse [501]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.7))"

 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
 at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incSta

Comment: am I using higher version of TestNG (latest) which is not compatible with my Java 1.6 ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Using Java 1.6, and eclipse Luna EE, installed TestNG, but its not show up in the menus, or run-as configurations. What i'm in doing wrong, uninstalled it and reinstalled it several times, do no avail, check workspace/.metadata./.log and no relevant entries. Others here are using same eclipse and TestNG plugin without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I tried to install 'eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64' and upgraded JDK from 1.6 to 1.7, it worked for me. So right now am not using Eclipse Luna anymore. 
Doing this will not disturb your Workspace. All your projects remains same. Only thing is you need to point eclipse to your previous Workspace itself.

Thanks all for your comments.